# UDP Server child process can't send

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to create a chat program using UDP. I've created a parent and a child process in both the client and the server to separately receive and send messages. Problem is the server can't send. Help please. Here's my code.

CLIENT

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        int sockfd;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(servaddr);
        char mesg[1024], rmesg[1024];
        pid_t pid;

        if(argc!=2){ 
            printf("Usage: %s <ip_addr>\n",argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }

        sockfd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(54321);
        inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&servaddr.sin_addr);

        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) {
            printf("Type 'exit' to Exit. \n");
            while(1){
                fgets(mesg,sizeof(mesg),stdin);
                sendto(sockfd,mesg,strlen(mesg),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,len);
                if(strcmp(mesg, "exit\n") == 0)
                    break;
            }
            close(sockfd);
            kill(pid, SIGINT);
            exit(0);
        }else{
            while(1){
                memset(rmesg,0,sizeof(rmesg));
                if(recv(sockfd,rmesg,sizeof(rmesg),0) > 0 ){
                    printf("From Server: %s", rmesg);
                }
            }
        }
        close(sockfd);
        return 0;
    }
```

SERVER

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        int sockfd1;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        char cli_ip[32];
        char mesg[1024], smesg[1024];
            pid_t  pid1;

        sockfd1 = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(54321);
        inet_ntop(AF_INET,(struct in_addr *) &cliaddr.sin_addr, cli_ip, sizeof(cli_ip) );

        if ( bind( sockfd1, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) ) < 0 ){
            perror(NULL);
            exit(-1);
        }

        pid1 = fork();
        if(pid1 == 0){
            while(1){
                memset(mesg,0,sizeof(mesg));
                if( recvfrom(sockfd1,mesg,sizeof(mesg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len) > 0 ){
                    printf("From client: %s",mesg);
                }
            }
        }else{
            printf("Type 'exit' to Exit. \n");
            while(1){
                fgets(smesg,sizeof(smesg),stdin);
                sendto(sockfd1,smesg,strlen(smesg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,len);
                if(strcmp(smesg, "exit\n") == 0)
                    break;
            }
            close(sockfd1);
            kill(pid1, SIGINT);
            exit(0);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This code fully lacks any error checking on reads and writes and most other system calls! This is bad and unwise in the first place, as detecting errors is the only possibility to react to them. And at least it helps a lot during development, testing and debugging!

Comment: Why is the server calling `inet_ntop` on an uninitialized `cliaddr.sin_addr`? It's also calling `recvfrom()` in a child process, but the parent process is trying to use that `cliaddr` in its `sendto` -- the structure isn't updated in the parent process.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely in the client:

> ```
> while(1){
>     if(recv(sockfd,rmesg,sizeof(rmesg),0) > 0 ){
>         printf("From Server: %s", rmesg);
>     }
> }
> ```

You are calling **`recv` on an unconnected socket**. You're likely getting an error (probably `ENOTCONN`) which you are ignoring. And I believe you're also seeing high CPU usage on the clients, since it is continuously looping, failing each system call.

The solution is to use `recvfrom` instead. Alternatively you can call `connect` on the socket, even if it is `SOCK_DGRAM`, but this is not normally done.

Comment: if you don't call `connect()`, you have to call `bind()` to set the local port to listen on.

Comment: @Barmar, you do not need a socket to be connected for UDP. As long as it is bound to the port on which the sender is sending data, the receiver hsould be able to receive it. Of course, a UDP socket can also call connect(), as you mentioned.

Comment: @ManojPandey Isn't that what I said? You seem to be commenting on the answer, not my comment.

Comment: Agreed (+1). Thnx. My comment was for @cnicutar.

Comment: @ManojPandey I never said you need to connect it for UDP. You need to connect it if you want to use straight `recv`.

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure what you're saying, but in this case `bind` isn't necessary.

Comment: @cnicutar agreed (+1)

Comment: Tried both suggestions of @cnicutar but didn't work. The code works if it wasn't divided into two processes but it would just be a 'type message and wait for reply to be able to send again' chat program.

Comment: @cnicutar If you don't call `bind()` or `connect()`, what local port will it get the packets from?

Comment: @cnicutar, you probably should elaborate that. The receivers port number should be known (somehow, communicated) to the sender. Also, a random port is allocated only for the client side and that too only when calling connect(). But, as a first cut I would recommend Barmar to stay away from connect() and simply rely on simpler UDP semantics.

Answer (score 0):

WHy are you using hte same socket for both server and client? This does not make sense. A simpler alternative would be to use two threads. One thread handling the server socket and the other thread handling the client thread. And ofcourse, you would need to have two sockets as well -- one for the server and one for the client. Also, the sendto() needs to have the address and port information of the receiver.

Comment: @user2757209 If you are running code separately for client and server, why are you doing a fork() for both client/server? You shoudl use threads to handle this -- they are more efficient. Creating a process with each client is very inefficient.

Comment: I don't know how to use threads yet, so i settled for fork(). Efficiency doesn't really matter, and this is just a two way communication program..

Comment: For the current option, you can still use the main process to get your tasks done since sendto() is a non-blocking call. If you need to scale at some point, then I would strongly recommend spending some time on Pthreads. Creating a process is way more expensive than creating threads. It will be worth the time spent, especially when you are trying to scale.